# Can I run KDE-based Programs without completely installing KDE?

Tags: kde

I want to be able to use some programs that depend on KDE, such as Krita and Kdenlive, but I don't want to have to install the KDM.

If I install Krita on Ubuntu, I suffer many problems trying to open it.  Looking at the terminal output, it seems they are related to some missing KDE folders or something like that.

Is it possible to install the KDE directories hierarchy without need to install the entire KDE Plasma Desktop?

Comment: Can you provide additional details, such as the terminal output you speak of?

Answer (score 3):

The thing about KDE is that if you try to install a component of the desktop, such as Krita, it will require, and thus depend on and automatically install, all (or most) of the base KDE programs. It's a very centralized software. When you install all the KDE desktop packages, however, the most harm they will cause is taking a lot of disk space. Your standard Ubuntu desktop will remain unchanged as long as that is the session type you select upon login.